# How to develop a script in perl which can delete the data in sub folders recursively and also the parent directory?

Tags: linux, perl

Hi have the folder structure as follows

```
mishel/      #Parent directory  
      mike1  #sub file of mishel  
      minni1 #sub file of mishel  
      rosy1  #sub file of mishel
        rocky/      #sub directory of mishel
             missi  #subfile of rocky
             marsh  #subfile of rocky
             milly  #subfile of rocky 
               monu/     #sub directory of rocky
                  mike  #sub file of monu
                  minni #sub file of monu
                  rosy  #sub file of monu
```

so here is my question:
I want to use a script which automatically deletes all the files and sub folders at a single shot.

If we use the function "rmdir(dirname)" the directory must empty. So is there any chance of deleting starting from the sub directory to the parent directory.

Comment: This question belongs on stack overflow, not here.  But Jenny D's recursive approach is a good one, just watch out for symlinks to other directories.

Comment: `rm -rf the-victim-directory` and be done with it.

Answer (score 6):

Write a function that takes a directory as an argument. Have that function do a `readdir` in the directory. For each item returned by readdir, check if it's a file - if so, delete it. If it's a directory, call the function again with the subdirectory as an argument. If there are no items (other than `.` and `..`), delete the directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Path::Class;
my $dir = dir('foo');
$dir->recurse(callback => sub {
    unlink $_[0] if !$_[0]->is_dir;
});
$dir->rmtree(0, 1);
```

Or :

```
use File::Path ('rmtree');
rmtree('foo', 0, 0);
```

See http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=605930

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e 'system "find mishel -delete"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `remove_tree` function of the [`File::Path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html) module